# Implementing a Singleton pattern in C#

Tags: c#, singleton

Is this the best way to implement this pattern in C#?

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }

    static Singleton() {}
    private Singleton() {}
}
```

Comment: [Singleton is an antipattern](http://thetechcandy.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/singletons-is-anti-pattern/).

Comment: Please watch: ["Global State and Singletons"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I use [Jon Skeet's version](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) of a *thread safe* Singleton with fully lazy instantiation in C#:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    // Thread safe Singleton with fully lazy instantiation á la Jon Skeet:
    // http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx
    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Nested.instance;
        }
    }

    class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

It works wonders for me! It's really easy to use, just get the instance from the Instance property like so; `SingletonName instance = SingletonName.Instance;`

Comment: Wouldn't GetInstance be more appropriate for what is essentially an accessor? Or is that convention different in C#?

Comment: I think that Instance is sufficient enough, but I suppose YMMV.

Comment: Is there some specific benefit from creating a nested class?

Comment: @AnnaLear: I believe that Jon Skeet explains it better himself than I can at the moment, check out the link. :)

Comment: The nested class is what makes it lazy.  The runtime will not instantiate the Singleton instance until Singleton.Instance is called.  That way, if you have other static members or something on Singleton, you can access them without creating the Singleton instance.

Comment: I'd like to encourage everyone to read Jon Skeet's article (following the link Zolomon has provided), as it coverts almost all answers in this topic, listing all their pros and cons.

Comment: This is also thread safe.

Comment: That's pretty darn clever.  But I had to read Jon's article to actually understand what's going on.  But the next guy that maintains your code probably won't get all the trickery just by looking at it.  I'd add a comment that links to Jon's article.

Comment: @AngryHacker: That's what I do in my implementations. ;)

Comment: How would you use this in tests - what if you needed to mock it or parts of it?

Comment: @Chris: You wouldn't.  That's part of why singletons suck -- they're essentially hidden global state, making it nearly impossible to reliably test code that contains or uses them.

Comment: @cHao +1 good job on pointing out the suckiness of singletons!

Comment: It's actually not all that bad.  Have the singleton class implement an interface and mock that interface.  It's not like any version of the class is static, just the one instance.

Comment: @Jesse: Only problem is, code that uses singletons almost always ends up going to get them itself.  There end up being calls to `Singleton.Instance` scattered all over the place.  You can't easily mock your way around that.  If code expected to be passed a Singleton that it'd use, then sure, you could easily mock it.  At which point you have dependency injection, though, and no longer need a singleton.

Comment: @cHao Not quite true; some pay-for test products can mock static classes, and Pex can mock static methods: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/

Comment: @ChrisMoschini : Yes, you can Mole it out, Pex it out or even use the old TypeMock isolator but when you need to replace it then.. CTRL-SHIFT-H... :(

Comment: Try googling "ambient context" for some good ideas of how to have your single return an abstract type which has a default concrete value at runtime but which would be easily replaceable for testing.

Answer (score 18):

I always use this, it allows lazy initialisation of generics, instead of creating a new singleton class for each type of singleton I want. It's also threadsafe but does not use locks on every access.

```
public static class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private T instance = null;

    public T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref instance, new T(), null);

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

If you're unfamiliar with the interlocked class, it performs atomic operations in a manner which is often quicker than a lock. Three possible cases:

1) **First access by a single thread**. Probably roughly the same performance as the obvious method using a lock

2) **First access by many threads at the same time**. Many threads might enter the interlocked exchange, in which case several items may get constructed but only 1 will "win". So long as your constructor has no global side effects (which is really shouldn't) behaviour will be correct. Performance will be slightly less than a lock, because of multiple allocations, but the overhead is small and this is a very rare case.

3) **Later accesses**. No locking or interlocked operations, this is pretty much optimal and is obviously the majority case.

Comment: +1 for good solution, but the problem #2 requiring your Constructors to have no side effects has always scared me off this approach.

Comment: How often do your constructors have side effects? I've always considered that to be a pretty bad code smell. Especially in multithreaded code!

Comment: Additionally, your constructor can have side effects so long as they're threadsafe and do not assume that this is the only instance to be created. Remember, several instances may be created but only one will "win", so if you do have side effects they'd better be implemented properly!

Comment: @Martin: Isn't the whole point of singletons that only one instance can be created?  It'd seem to me that relying on that assumption is a quite reasonable thing to do...

Comment: @cHao true, but as I said before I consider any side effects in a constructor which leak beyond the instance being constructed one of the worst code smells, doubly so in multithreaded code. Assuming we agree on this, there's no way constructing 2 instances can have any external affect on your program.

Comment: -1, Not thread safe (constructor could be called several times), thus defeating the purpose of a singleton.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can take advantage of the [System.Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) class. It ensures the instance is created only once.

Comment: You should add a code sample since I believe this is by far the best way to implement a singleton with .NET 4.0.

Comment: A code sample is available at http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx ("sixth version")

Answer (score 9):

I use a pattern similar to one already posted, but with the following difference:

```
public sealed class Logging
{
    static Logging instance = null;
    static readonly object lockObj = new object();

    private Logging()
    {
    }

    public static Logging Logger
    {
        get
        {
            **if (instance == null)**
            {
                 lock (lockObj)
                 {
                     if (instance == null)
                     {
                         instance = new Logging();
                     }

                 }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

}

The reason being that it avoids calling lock every time, which can help you with performance.  So you check for null, then, if it is null, lock it.  Then you have to check for null again (because someone may have come in right that second) but then you should be ok.  That way, you'll only hit the lock the first time (or two), and blow past it without locking the rest of the time.

Comment: Great example.I only have to add the name: it is called "Double-checked Locking"

Comment: The return statement needs to be outside of the first if(instance==null) statement. Otherwise it will not return an instance if the instance already exists.

Comment: @Dan quite correct, my mistake.

Answer (score 6):

I always use this solution if I have to implement a Singleton in C#

```
public sealed class Logging
    {
        static Logging instance = null;
        static readonly object lockObj = new object();

        private Logging()
        {
        }

        public static Logging Logger
        {
            get
            {
                lock (lockObj)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Logging();
                    }
                   return instance;
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Compared to your solution this is threadsafe and uses a lazy-creation method. (The object is only instantiated if actually needed)

The eager vs. lazy creation isn't really worth a discussion in this example, but I would whenever possible use the thread-safe implementation.

Comment: This is a very bad solution to the problem, it uses a lock on every single access. Which has a very high overhead.

Comment: @Martin: The overhead is not that onerous unless you say `Logging.Logger.DoThis()` and `Logging.Logger.DoThat()` every time.  Which i'd prefer to avoid that anyway, as (1) it pretty much entrenches the Logging class, making it even more of a pain to swap out for something else later, and (2) `Logging.Logger` will, by the definition of a singleton, always return the same thing, so re-getting it each time is silly.  Oh, and (3) it's repetitive, and i hate repetition.

Comment: You're using a singleton now, but later you may wish to change your singleton so, for example, it swaps out to a new logger when the file gets full - so I tend to try to avoid caching the singleton. There's no point keeping hundreds of references to something around when you can centralise access in one place easily and efficiently with e.g. double checked locking

Answer (score 4):

Dependency Injection containers like Unity support a singleton concept. Unity is from Microsoft (and is open source), but there are [lots of open source DI containers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example from Wikipedia's Double-checked locking page:

```
public class MySingleton
{
    private static object myLock = new object();
    private static MySingleton mySingleton = null;

    private MySingleton()
    { }

    public static MySingleton GetInstance()
    {
        if (mySingleton == null)    // check
        {
            lock (myLock)
            {
                if (mySingleton == null)    // double check
                {
                    MySingleton newSingleton = new MySingleton();
                    System.Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier();
                    mySingleton = newSingleton;
                }
            }
        }

        return mySingleton;
    }
}
```

Notice the use of `System.Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier();`, unlike GWLlosa's answer. See [The "Double-checked locking is broken" declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) for an explanation. (It is written for Java, but the same principles apply.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation that uses [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx):

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IFoo> __instance
        = new Lazy<IFoo>(valueFactory: () => new Foo(), isThreadSafe: true);

    private Foo() { }

    public static IFoo Instance { get { return __instance.Value; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to I would like to suggest a simple way using volatile keyword , static variable are not thread safe but atomic execution are considered as thread safe. by using volatile we can enforce atomic operation.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static **volatile** readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }
    private Singleton() { }
}
```

Locking is not the sure way to go , as it is expensive.

I like john skeet way of creating the singleton way of creating the objects.